# How to combine two attributes in one object

Tags: javascript, angular, object, post, request

I want to combine two attributes of the object result of post request in angular in an object.

[image]

when create or edit a sitearea I want to return city and country into one object instead of return it like the image above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood the question, but if your goal is to simple combine city and country to single attribute, simply concatenate them:

```
mySiteArea.cityAndCountry = mySiteArea.city + ' ' + mySiteArea.country;
```

Let me know if that's what you wanna do.

Comment: when getting the object from the request I want create an object inside sitearea result  that contain city and country attribute together

Comment: So yes, you have it in the answer